# Average results of lapply function in R

Tags: r, lapply, mean, sapply

I have a function returning data frame like this:

```
TERM  Freq

GO1    1
GO2    5
GO3    4
```

I'm calling the function multiple times using lapply, and I want to average all the results  receive (Freq column) by the TERM column. Note that each run may return slightly different terms.

The results of the lapply function looks like:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Further, this question would really benefit from being reproducible (and a picture of a summary of data is not helpful). Please read from https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info, and then [edit] your question and add sample data using `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative sample. If your function is not important, then give a sample of the result from that `lapply(., yourfunc)` call so that we can better see what you want to aggregate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **dplyr** solution.

Sample data:

```
dat1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
TERM  Freq
GO1    1
GO2    5
GO3    4')


dat2 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
TERM  Freq
GO1    1
GO2    2
GO3    1')



dat3 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = '
TERM  Freq
GO1    2
GO2    3
GO3    4')


lst <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3)
```

Solving take two steps.  First combine the list into a single data frame.  Then perform the grouping and summarization.  Like this:

```
library(dplyr)


grp <- bind_rows(lst) %>% 
  group_by(TERM) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(Freq))

grp
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   TERM   mean
#   <chr> <dbl>
# 1 GO1    1.33
# 2 GO2    3.33
# 3 GO3    3
```